# image is not displayed after getting the path from the database

Tags: java, html, eclipse

I have tried the image uploading code in java.Images are upload in -

`D:\bridge\Project\.metadata\.plugins\ org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\bridghc\Example\image-folder\2nd page.jpg` this directory.

This fully path is also inserted in database.When i fetch the path from database i get the same result but when i write

`<img id="0" src="D:\bridge\Project\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\bridghc\Example\image-folder\2nd page.jpg" name="txtrepimg0">.`

In the web page i am not able to fetch the image.I got failed to load url.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The `src` attribute in the `img` tag only accepts web addresses as targets, not local directories. So the path should look something like `http://mysite/images/myimage.jpg`

Comment: so what is the solution in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You should store relative path into database not Actual path of file. you should only store 
file name, as your folder is fixed to store images

> 2nd page.jpg

and use the following in img tag

```
<img id="0" src="application_name/your-relative-path-of-image-folder/2nd page.jpg
```

" name="txtrepimg0">

like

```
<img id="0" src="/bridghc/Example/image-folder/2nd page.jpg" name="txtrepimg0">
```

In your case application name is bridghc

Answer (score 0):

Try change your upload path to something relative to your website location.

For example, if your webfiles(html, css, javascript, etc...) are in:

```
D:\bridge\Project\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\bridghc\Example
```

add a folder like "image-folder" in a relative path like

```
D:\bridge\Project\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\bridghc\Example\image-folder
```

save the relative path in database

```
\image-folder\image.png
```

and use it in your website

```
<img id="0" src="\image-folder\image.jpg" name="txtrepimg0">
```